# simplest way implement ESC circuit for drone?

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, drone, quad-copter, rp2040

I'm designing a fun little quadcopter PCB based around the RP2040 chip and am interested to incorporate the ESCs in my design, all on one board. They don't need to be too fancy in terms of features and should be fine with 10A of motor current.

Is there a standard go-to circuit for this in the community?

Or even do we think it's a good idea to use the RP2040 chip for managing the ESC controls also? It seems like the chip should be powerful enough to manage the power circuits as well as the flight controls, Which would give the added bonus of not having 5 microcontrollers on my circuit!

Comment: Hello and welcome.  What is "ESC"?

Comment: Thanks. An ESC is an Electronic Speed Controller used to generate the AC power required to drive a quadcopter's motors